# Spring Data JPA does not work with transaction isolation "READ_UNCOMMITTED"

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, transactions, spring-data

There are two threads, and two transactions bound to each thread:

`DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.workflow.consumer.RecordEventConsumer$MockitoMock$1882263982.handleRecordsAddedEvent]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED; ''`

`Creating new transaction with name [com.workflow.statemachine.action.CreateContentAction.execute]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED; ''`

Both isolation levels are `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. But when first thread insert something in database with

```
repository.saveAndFlush(contextObject)
```

Where repository is `JpaRepository<T, I> repository`

And there are actual logs that insertion happened `DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into task_unit ...etc`

The transaction from second thread still could not retrieve this very object with neither of this:

```
repository.getOne(id);
repository.findOne(id);
entityManager.find(class, id);
```

More than this, I've tried to connect to the db directly and fire

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT * from task_unit
```

And still no success.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: Postgres does not allow dirty reads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I read your question right, then this manual excepr answers:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html

> In PostgreSQL, you can request any of the four standard transaction
>   isolation levels, but internally only three distinct isolation levels
>   are implemented, i.e. **PostgreSQL's Read Uncommitted mode behaves like
>   Read Committed**. This is because it is the only sensible way to map the
>   standard isolation levels to PostgreSQL's multiversion concurrency
>   control architecture.

emphasis mine

Comment: no problem. https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/transaction-iso.html  `Read uncommited (Чтение незафиксированных данных) Допускается, но не в PG`